# android.os.StrictMode instances=2; limit=1

Tags: java, android

I use the `StrictMode` in my application , the api android 4.0.3, in my `BaseApp`
i detect all.

```
    builder.detectAll();
    builder.penaltyLog(); 
    StrictMode.VmPolicy vmp = builder.build();
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(vmp);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder builder1= new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder();
    builder1.detectAll();
    builder1.penaltyLog();
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy tdp=builder1.build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tdp);
```

then. I just call the  `this.finish()` , in my activity : always show this error.  why?  whether I use the  android:launchMode="singleInstance" in my Manifest.xml,they always show this error why?

```
06-27 14:47:34.725: E/StrictMode(18592): class com.onecard.ui.business.AllBusinessActivity; instances=2; limit=1
06-27 14:47:34.725: E/StrictMode(18592): android.os.StrictMode$InstanceCountViolation: class com.onecard.ui.business.AllBusinessActivity; instances=2; limit=1
06-27 14:47:34.725: E/StrictMode(18592):    at android.os.StrictMode.setClassInstanceLimit(StrictMode.java:1)
```

Comment: Please have a look to this [entry in google forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/_EtuFAQH2Tc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is know issue of Strict Mode. I prefer to ignore it.

Comment: How do you ignore it? Is there a way to make it not crash for this error?

Comment: Answering my own comment. The crash only happens if you set penalty in builder to penaltyDeath.